# Improving handling of deleted answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications, deleted-answers

In a short period I stumbled on two occasions where an answer was deleted. I think in both cases it was the user who posted the answer, but I am only somewhat sure in the one case and hoping with the other.

My point is, it is strange to have useful answers suddenly deleted, without any explanations to it. Luckily I had some comment conversation in the first case and could convince to undelete. In the other case, I was able to retrieve the user name through my summary of stated questions.

However, it would be quite nice as a questioner, to have an explanation, why some answer was deleted (by user / by mod / flagged) and a hint to where to state an undelete request.

I was thinking, like a possibility to notify the user/mod, that there is a request to undelete.

Further, I am not sure if using the *@llonesmiz* to notify him via a comment on my own question, will even notify him. If not - how could I inform him other than to e.g. spam on someone elses question, which he answered?

This is a suggestion based on my experience, which in my opinion could have been better, therefore suggest room for improvement.

Here are the two occasions of mine:

convinced to undelete:

[How to set serial_port flow_control to other than none under boost asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011282/how-to-set-serial-port-flow-control-to-other-than-none-under-boost-asio)

will hopefully undelete:

[How can I reset with send_break in this example of a boost::asio application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971601/how-can-i-reset-with-send-break-in-this-example-of-a-boostasio-application)

Comment: ok, will try that, if the user does not react - but should this be the default way?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't think it is the default way. I think the default way is posting the answer yourself and self-accept your answer.

Comment: Don't flag posts for undeletion if the original poster deleted them. It's not our job to undelete answers if the poster doesn't want them around. I will reject a flag like that and do nothing. I expect other mods would do the same.

Comment: @nhahtdh in case I did get the answer, which don't have to be true in every case - eighter way this seems wrong to me, it is not my credit to have

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ - I don't wan't to make it your job - I just would like to have a possibility to contact, whoever deleted a good answer to MY question

Comment: @Jook You can always find a post on that person's profile and post a comment under it. Once you're sure they've seen it, delete it. That's the best you can do.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ - ok, I will do that, or what nhahtdh suggested in his answer - but still, I feel like there could be a better way to handle those situations.

Comment: FTR this user (llonesmiz) has just deleted his account. I hope he's okay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try contacting the original author. If no reply after a day or two, you can write a self-answer that details how you solved the problem and give credit to the original author. Then you can self-accept your answer. If you feel it is unfair to take the rep, you can make it community wiki, so that you don't gain rep from it. It is better to leave the question answered rather than leaving it in an unanswered state, while you have actually found the solution.